# Saving a json/txt file to S3 from Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using lambda to run a program. Once it is run I need to save some data as a json file or txt. I tried to see if there is a way to write a file in lambda and save it but there are no write permissions it is read only. So I am now thinking of saving this json object in S3, so that i can retrieve it later. Is there a way to upload to s3 without writing a file and just upload an object

Comment: Your question laks details and is unclear. What do you mean " no write permissions it is read only"? Write permissions to where?

Comment: I came to know I can write temporarily in '/tmp/' path.
Earlier  I tried something like this. 
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    data = {
        'a':1,
        'b':2,
        'c':3
    }
    jfile = json.dumps(data)
    with open("json_file.json","w") as file:
        file.write(jfile)
        
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }

Comment: Please update the question with new code using properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: Currently facing some issue with editing the question.  (Too many pendding edits on Stackoverflow). Will do it once stack over flow resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Lambda is just another runtime environment for your Python code. You can utilize the boto3 SDK to upload your file to S3.
Something along the lines of the following should work:

```
import json

import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object('BUCKET_NAME', 'FILE_NAME.json')

obj.put(Body=(bytes(json.dumps(data).encode('UTF-8'))))
```